# Array object property empty when passing the array as argument directly

Tags: javascript, arrays, arguments, javascript-objects

I have this object:

```
function Student(name, grades) {
    this.name = name;
    this.grades = grades;

    this.getName = () => this.name;
    this.getGrades = () => this.grades;
}
```

`grades` is supposed to be an array. But when I do this:

```
let student = new Student('James', [1, 2, 3])
console.log(student.getGrades)
```

the array `grades` is empty. What am I doing wrong? Is there something wrong with passing an array directly as an argument?

Thanks!

---

Comment: `getGrades` is a function.

Comment: You aren't calling the function ... `console.log(student.getGrades())`

Comment: There is nothing in your code however as @charlietfl mentioned you are not calling the function

Comment: Wow! What an amazingly stupid mistake from me... thanks com! :D